# How to name a page that contains 3 features that have no relationship to each other?

Tags: website-design, terminology

I'm working on an intranet that requires users to input 3 different sets of information.

One set is about their relationship to their organization (Partner, On leave, Applicant, etc). 
The second set is about their location (Normally living in the UK). 
The third set is the team they work in (International office).

I need to have the results (summary) of this information on the same page, because all of the sets have a start and end date and have to align. (Such as having the same start or end date on a location and a team).

How do I name this page when all 3 features have no correlation of information or user tasks. I realize I could summary, but a summary of what? What is the collection of these 3 features called?

Comment: Is that a User Dashboard? Updates Dashboard perhaps. What is the name of the project? The project brief should have defined something.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the name should describe what the task is about. Something like 'Tell us about you ...' or 'Before we start ...'.

Answer (score 1):

How to name a page? Here's a technique to try:

Ask yourself two questions: (1) Why are we making users do these things? (2) Why are they all on the same screen?

Answer the questions aloud. Talk to one of your colleagues about it. Ask them the same questions. Get conversational. Say a lot about it. Jot down the significant words you use in your answers. Some of those words or phrases might be (or might lead to) the best header for that page.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with Fylgge and say that the page should be named for it's overarching purpose.

"About Me", "My Demographics", "My Data".

People won't be too confused if you present it as an amalgam of information being gathered. Just make sure that you have clear headers for each individual section, so the user knows what is being asked of them at every step.